# Magento GeoIp - Multiple Websites - Auto Redirection

Tags: language, internationalization

Hi there just a quick question/advice about GeoIP redirection and Magento

I have a store that we currently run in the UK and ship only to UK addresses. We wish to start selling to the rest of Europe (Euros) so we need two website views as we want the to be processed in base currency but also because we want to set different pricing levels for Euros than GBP not just a conversion.

The client wants customers to be auto redirected to the region which they are from which is fairly straightforward. Using apache mod_geoip to accomplish.

However, I'm wondering what the advantages and disadvantages of auto redirecting customers in terms of seo?

Our current intended setup would be (all of these would be english, they don't want translations):

http://www.our-store.co.uk/ - English UK Store - GBP
http://www.our-store.co.uk/eu/ - English European Store - Euros

My argument is that if it's auto redirecting, then in seo terms that doesn't seem like a good idea to me as if the search engine trawling the site is viewing from a specific region then it would only be able to see one instance of the website?

However, the client doesn't want people from other regions to see prices from opposing regions because they would be alot higher for one region than another hence the want for autoredirection...

Does anyone have any advice on how I should go about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should buy a .eu domain, Google doesn't like subdirectories. You will also have to write scripts to update the Euro pricing on change or keep two prices lists.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to not list your Euro store on Google for now and to redirect Euro customers with geoIP to your Euro store view.

At a later stage when you have 'rich snippets' and such like populating your search results with pricing, you can then add hreflang tags on the pages and in the sitemap, then set your new store front to be 'index, follow'.

For your stores you may want to add /uk for the uk store, the homepage will work fine without adding store codes to URLs.

You will also need to set pricing at website level scope.